# count records by grouping of two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to count how many variations of `amount` there are per `fk_id`. If there is more than one variation then I want the record to be returned otherwise I want the record to be ignored.

What is wrong with the below statement?

```
SELECT *, count(fk_id) AS `count` FROM table
WHERE count > 1
GROUP BY fk_id, amount;
```

Table:

```
+-----------+----------+--------------+
| id        | fk_id    | amount       |
+-----------+----------+--------------+
|         1 | 100      | 5            |
|         2 | 200      | 10           |
|         3 | 200      | 10           |
|         4 | 200      | 10           |
|         5 | 200      | 15           |
+-----------+----------+--------------+
```

Expected output:

```
+-----------+----------+--------------+--------------+
| id        | fk_id    | amount       | count        |
+-----------+----------+--------------+--------------+
|         2 | 200      | 10           | 2            |
+-----------+----------+--------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use an aggregate function in `WHERE` clause. Use `HAVING` clause instead:

```
SELECT MIN(id) as id,fk_id,amount, count(fk_id)-1 AS `count` 
FROM table
GROUP BY fk_id, amount
HAVING count(fk_id)>1
```

Result:

```
ID  FK_ID   AMOUNT  COUNT
2   200     10      2
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c0c2/2).